# Remove incomprehensible element in the result of a jupyternotbook's cell

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried to plot a horizontal bar chart for a pandas.core.series.Series in a Jupyternotebook. The output graph has an element `<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x7f1f8442afd0>` on top of it. Can someone please explain what that is and how I can remove/hide that element in the output? Thanks.[image: Horizontal Bar Chart]

Comment: Add `plt.show()` at the end of your code?

Comment: Thanks. @Erfan. Would you mind posting it as the answer so that I could accept it? Do you why that element was displayed without `plt.show()`?